# Is there a way to override packageName in sbt while building dist?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an sbt project. I have defined the packageName as follows in the build.sbt

packageName in Universal := "project"

Is there a way to override packageName when we do sbt dist in commmand line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```sh
sbt 'set packageName := "newName"' publish # or
sbt 'set packageName in Universal := "newName"' publish
```

?

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Custom commands can be used to modify the build state like so

```
commands += Command.command("distWithPackageNameOverride") { state =>
  """set packageName in Universal := "foo"""" :: "dist" :: state
}
```

where executing `sbt distWithPackageNameOverride` should output `foo.zip` under

```
yourapp/target/universal/foo.zip
```